# Click event on TinyMCE 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

Recently I tried to integrate TinyMce 4.0 in my web application. I want to put a click event for when I click on the textarea but it doesn't work. I have looked on the official documentation, and I've tried the following code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
          console.debug('Editor was clicked: ' + e.target.nodeName);
      });
   }
```

There are an error that appear : "TypeError: ed.onClick is undefined".

So, I have tried to put directly a onclick event on the iframe but it's a failure :

```
$("iframe").contents().bind('click', function(){
...
});
```

**Do you have any ideas on how to do this?**

Comment: Where are you test(browser)?

Comment: Hi, I've tested on the last version of Google Chrome and the last version of Firefox.

Answer (score 13):

TinyMCE v4 has changed things from v3 - try:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.on("click", function() {
        alert("Editor Clicked!  Element: " + this.target.nodeName);
    });
};
```

Comment: Important to mention that parameter `ed` in function for 'click' does not contains editor instance. This was my case for 'init' event  handling. To access editor instance (originator of event), use - `this` keyword, eg: 
`editor.on('init', function () {
var doc = this.contentDocument;
});`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you could try

```
$(ed.getDoc()).bind('click', function(){
...
});
```

Update:
Looks like there is no editor initialized to that point of time. Try

```
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, e) {
        ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
          console.debug('Editor was clicked: ' + e.target.nodeName);
        });
      });
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried your code but I've the following error: "ReferenceError: ed is not defined". I even tried (to test) to replace "ed" to "window.tinyMCE.get("idOfMyTextarea")" and I've again the previous error.

Comment: I've tried your code: it works fine for the version 3 but not for the version 4. When I try with the version 4, I've the following error: "TypeError: ed.onInit is undefined". The error appears only on the version 4!

Comment: hmmm, i am not familiar with the new version 4 that much by now - sorry